# How configure https and disable http in CentOS 5.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, https

How can I configure Apache to access Subversion only through HTTPS and not through HTTP. HTTP need to use for access some other application in the same machine.

Please help on this. I am in the middle.

Thanks for the great help

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should declare two virtual hosts using Apache VirtualHost directive, one for port 443 (HTTPS) and another one for port 80. Since virtual hosts can have completely different configs, you can easily serve Subversion on 443 and anything else on 80.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to have both http & https for both applications. Set them up on a Virtual domain, and assign a subdomain for them ie subversion.mydomain.com and otherapp.mydomain.com.